# Getting Null Pointer Exception in Chrome & Mozilla, getparameter sending null value

Tags: java, servlets

Facing problem in `getparameter(filepath)`. It's sending the null value for Chrome and Firefox but working fine for IE. I found some links indicating that `getparameter` is not working fine with servlet 2.5 but my problem is still not resolved. If you have an alternative or suggestion you are most welcome for giving a reply.

Please see  servlet and class file:

**upload.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>File Upload</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <center>
            <h3>File Upload:</h3>
              Select a file to upload: 
              <form action = "ImportExcelServlet" method="post">

                 <input type = "file" name="file_path" size = "50" />
                 <br /></br>
                 <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
              </form>
        </center>
            <form method="post" action="ImportExcelServlet">
                 <input type="submit" value="Import" />
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**DataGrid.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<%  
// retrieve your list from the request, with casting 
//ArrayList<Category> list = (ArrayList<Category>) request.getAttribute("servletName");
Object[][] excelData=(Object[][])request.getAttribute("data");%>
<table id="customers">
<%for(int i=0;i<excelData.length;i++){%><tr><%for(int j=0;j<excelData[0].length;j++){ if(i==0){ %>
<th>
<%=excelData[i][j]%>
</th>
<%}else{%>
<td>
<%=excelData[i][j]%>
</td>
<%}%>
<%}%>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<script>
function fnExcelReport()
{
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('customers'); // id of table

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Grid.xlsx");
    }  
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  

    return (sa);
}
</script>
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT </button>
</body>
</html>
```

### ImportExcelSevlet.java

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class ReadExcel
 */
@WebServlet("/ImportExcelServlet")
public class ImportExcelServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ImportExcelServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //doGet(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Object[][] excelData=null;

        String filepath=request.getParameter("file_path");
        excelData=ReadWriteExcel.readXLSXFile(filepath);
        request.setAttribute("data",excelData); 
        getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DataGrid.jsp").forward(request,response);
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    }

}
```

### ReadWriteExcel.java

```
package test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class  ReadWriteExcel {
public static Object[][] readXLSXFile(String filepath) throws IOException
{
    Object[][] excelData = null;
    try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int x=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int y=sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        excelData=new Object[x][y];

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        int i=0;
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int j=0;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        excelData[i][j]=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        excelData[i][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
}
```

Comment: as per the code i understand that you want to read the uploaded file in your servlet and do further processing on the data, you should upload a file using `method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">` not with only `method = "post"`

Comment: but as per your servlet code first few lines you are more interested in file path only `String filepath=request.getParameter("file_path");` what you will do with it , you need the content not the file path.

Comment: actually i need the path of the file for reading excel, and in the code file_path  i get, which is  uploaded by user and that path i am sending in class file using servlet

Comment: user will upload xls file only ryt? why you want to read the path, you have to read the data uploaded by the user not his/her local machine path , if you are designing any web application

Comment: ya right....so i have to store that  file on server and then fetch the data from there,but what if  i want to read the path from my local machine? It's just a query and thanks for suggestion...

Comment: you dont have to store anything that will be available in the request/response data when user submit the form..refer tutorials on file upload using servlets and jsp